# How to make a button take you to another form, when login details are correct? -c#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have a created a login form, and I need it so that when the user enters the correct details, clicking a button will take them to a user dashboard page.
I don't know what it's called, as I'm new to code so I can't search for it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to intercept the button event `OnClick` and then, from there, create a new instance of the form you want to display and show it calling `myNewForm.Show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Windows Forms you have to intercept the button event `Click` and then, from there, create a new instance of the form you want to display and show it calling `dashboardForm.Show();`

Here is an example:

**LoginForm.cs** class:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
  {
    public LoginForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string username = tbUsername.Text;
      string password = tbPassword.Text;

      // check credentials
      if (username == "user" && password == "pass")
      {
          DashboardForm dashboardForm = new DashboardForm();
          dashboardForm.Show();
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Error: credentials not valid");
      }
    }
  }
```

**DashboardForm.cs** class:

```
public partial class DashboardForm : Form
  {
    public DashboardForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the function for checking credentials, you just need to call it on your button Click event.

Your function should validate if the credentials are accepted or not.
if YES, show your dashboard.
if NO, show Error message to user.